# can't update images in mern project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am trying to make a product update page for my mern project. I created the create product and it works fine, but when I try to make update page it's not working fine. I use product id from database then select the product and fetch the product with the id and display in the fields. When update is clicked all the text details are updating but the problem is with the images.

I use `http://localhost:3000/uploads/${image}` for displaying the image in update page from database and it works fine, but when new image is added via `GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/[object%20File]` I get `404 (Not Found)` showing in console and the new images not inserting to the state "selectedImages".

I also tried using `URL.createObjectURL(image)` but got

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

Somebody please suggest a change in the code.

updateproduct.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AdminSidebar from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminSidebar'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import AdminHeader from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminheader'
import "./Admindashboard.css"

const UpdateProduct = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [mrp, setMrp] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const params = useParams();
  const [InStock, setInStock] = useState("");
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
  const [pid, setId] = useState("");
  const [DeletedImages, setDeletedImages] = useState([])

  const getSingleProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/getsingle-product/${params.id}`);
      console.log(data)

      setName(data.product.name);
      setId(data.product._id);
      setDescription(data.product.description);
      setSelectedImages(data.product.images);
      setMrp(data.product.mrp);
      setCategory(data.product.category);
      setInStock(data.product.InStock);
      if (data.success) {
        console.log("hai")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSingleProduct(params.id);
    console.log(params.id)
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  const getAllCategory = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/category/get-category");
      if (data.success) {
        setCategories(data.category);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCategory();
  }, []);

  //update product function
  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(selectedImages)

      const productData = new FormData();
      productData.append("name", name);
      productData.append("description", description);
      for (let img of selectedImages) {
        productData.append("images", img);
        console.log("forloop   "+img)
      }

      productData.append("mrp", mrp);
      productData.append("category", category);
      productData.append("InStock", InStock);

      const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, productData);
      //console.log(productData)

      if (data?.success) {
        toast.error(data?.message);
      } else {
        toast.success("Product Created Successfully");
        navigate("/dashboard/manage.vision/admin/products");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
  };

  const onSelectFile = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    console.log(selectedFiles)
    const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);

    setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(selectedFilesArray));
  
    // FOR BUG IN CHROME
    event.target.value = "";
  };
  console.log("out   "+selectedImages)
  const deleteHandler = (file) => {
    const remainingImages = selectedImages.filter((f) => f !== file);
    setSelectedImages(remainingImages);
    console.log(selectedImages)

    const objectUrlToDelete = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrlToDelete);
  };

  return (
    <body className='body'>
      <div className="container-fluid ">
        <div className="row">
          <AdminHeader />

          <AdminSidebar />

          <div className="col-md-3">
            <div>
              <button>Cancel</button><button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
              <div className="prgrid">
                <div className='upimg'>
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Images<hr></hr>
                  </h4>
                  <div >
                    <input type="file" id='upload' accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/webp" onChange={onSelectFile} multiple >

                    </input><label className="label" for="upload"><h3 >Upload +</h3></label>
                    <div className="images">
                      {selectedImages &&
                        selectedImages.map((image, index) => {
                          return (
                            <div key={image} className="image">
                              <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt="upload" className="primg" />
                              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="prdele" onClick={() => deleteHandler(image)} />
                              <p className="imgno">{index + 1}</p>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="prcat">
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Catagory</h4><hr></hr>

                  <Form.Select className="catsel" onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)
                  }>{categories?.map((c) => (
                    <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                      {c.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                  </Form.Select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="prinfo">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Info</h4><hr></hr>

                <Form.Label htmlFor="prname" className="prlab">Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  id="prname"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Product Name"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Group
                  className="mb-3"
                  controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
                >
                  <Form.Label className="prlab">Description</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} className="prdes" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Group>
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Pricing</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Maximum Retail Price</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="number"
                  id="prpice"
                  value={mrp}
                  onChange={(e) => setMrp(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Inventory Status</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Status</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className="stat" value={InStock} onChange={(e) => setInStock(e.target.value)}>
                  <option >Update Status</option>
                  <option value="0">In Stock</option>
                  <option value="1">Out Of Stock</option>
                </Form.Select></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  )
}

export default UpdateProduct
```

createproduct.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AdminSidebar from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminSidebar'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import AdminHeader from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminheader'
import "./Admindashboard.css"

const CreateProduct = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [mrp, setMrp] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [InStock, setInStock] = useState("");
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);

  const getAllCategory = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/category/get-category");
      if (data.success) {
        setCategories(data.category);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCategory();
  }, []);

  const onSelectFile = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);

    setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(selectedFilesArray));

    // FOR BUG IN CHROME
    event.target.value = "";
  };

  const deleteHandler = (file) => {
    const remainingImages = selectedImages.filter((f) => f !== file);
    setSelectedImages(remainingImages);

    const objectUrlToDelete = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrlToDelete);
  };

  //create product function
  const handleCreate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {

      const productData = new FormData();
      productData.append("name", name);
      productData.append("description", description);
      for (let img of selectedImages) {
        productData.append("images", img);
      }

      productData.append("mrp", mrp);
      productData.append("category", category);
      productData.append("InStock", InStock);

      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/v1/product/create-product", productData);

      if (data?.success) {
        toast.error(data?.message);
      } else {
        toast.success("Product Created Successfully");
        navigate("/dashboard/manage.vision/admin/products");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
  };

  return (
    <body className='body'>
      <div className="container-fluid ">
        <div className="row">
          <AdminHeader />

          <AdminSidebar />

          <div className="col-md-3">
            <div>
              <button>Cancel</button><button onClick={handleCreate}>Create</button>
              <div className="prgrid">
                <div className='upimg'>
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Images<hr></hr>
                  </h4>
                  <div >
                    <input type="file" id='upload' accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/webp" onChange={onSelectFile} multiple >

                    </input><label className="label" for="upload"><h3 >Upload +</h3></label>
                    <div className="images">
                      {selectedImages &&
                        selectedImages.map((image, index) => {

                          return (
                            <div key={image} className="image">
                              <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt="upload" className="primg" />
                              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="prdele" onClick={() => deleteHandler(image)} />
                              <p className="imgno">{index + 1}</p>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="prcat">
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Catagory</h4><hr></hr>

                  <Form.Select className="catsel" onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)
                  }>{categories?.map((c) => (
                    <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                      {c.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                  </Form.Select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="prinfo">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Info</h4><hr></hr>

                <Form.Label htmlFor="prname" className="prlab">Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  id="prname"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Product Name"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Group
                  className="mb-3"
                  controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
                >
                  <Form.Label className="prlab">Description</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} className="prdes" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Group>
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Pricing</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Maximum Retail Price</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="number"
                  id="prpice"
                  value={mrp}
                  onChange={(e) => setMrp(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Inventory Status</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Status</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className="stat" value={InStock} onChange={(e) => setInStock(e.target.value)}>
                  <option >Update Status</option>
                  <option value="0">In Stock</option>
                  <option value="1">Out Of Stock</option>
                </Form.Select></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  )
}

export default CreateProduct
```

Routes.js

```js
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import {
  createProductController, deleteproduct, getSingleProduct,getAllProducts, updateProducts, storage
} from "../controllers/productController.js";
import { isAdmin, requireSignup } from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js";
const upload = multer({ storage })

const router = express.Router();

//routes
router.post(
  "/create-product", requireSignup,
  isAdmin, upload.array('images'), createProductController
);
//routes
router.put(
  "/update-product/:id",
  requireSignup,
  isAdmin,upload.array("images"),
  updateProducts

);

//get all products
router.get("/getall-product",requireSignup,
isAdmin,getAllProducts);

//get single products
router.get("/getsingle-product/:id", requireSignup,
isAdmin, getSingleProduct);

// //single product
// router.get("/get-product/:slug", getSingleProductController);

// //get photo
// router.get("/product-photo/:pid", productPhotoController);

// //delete product
router.delete("/delete-product/:id", requireSignup,
isAdmin, deleteproduct);

export default router;
```